# Put elements of a div in a css box

Tags: html, css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I used React and React-Bootstrap to build a website. I want to create a box with border inside a modal. This is my code.

**.JSX file**

```
<Modal.Header closeButton>
  <Modal.Title>Preview</Modal.Title>
</Modal.Header>
<Modal.Body>
  <Col md={6}>
    <div className="previewCard">
      <Col md={3}></Col>
      <Col md={7}>
        <p className="topicTH">Line1</p>
        <p className="topicTH">Line2</p>
        <p className="topicTH">Line3</p>
        <p className="topicTH">Line4</p>
        <p className="topicTH">Line5</p>
      </Col>
      <Col md={2}></Col>
    </div>
  </Col>
</Modal.Body>
<Modal.Footer></Modal.Footer>
```

**.CSS file**

```
div.previewCard{
  border-style: dashed;
}
```

[image]

As you can see, there is noting inside the box even it put elements inside `<div className="previewCard"></div>`. How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of div use Row:

```
<Row className="previewCard">
```